# editing UITableView row items swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have an addViewController and a UITableViewcontroller, I am trying to add a swipe-to-edit option inside my UITableViewCell, that will directly go to addViewController to edit.

error : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
pointing to this line
[image]

inside my UITableViewController

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
        var editNotesAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Edit") { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

            //methods
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editNoteSegue", sender: nil)

            var segue: UIStoryboardSegue!
            if segue.identifier! == "editNoteSegue" {

                var selectedItem: NSManagedObject = self.notesList[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row] as NSManagedObject
                let IVC: AddNoteViewController = segue.destinationViewController as AddNoteViewController

                IVC.notes = selectedItem.valueForKey("notes") as String
                IVC.existingItem = selectedItem

            }


        }

        //change the background color of the swipe-to-edit
        //editNotesAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        editNotesAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "editBG")!)

        var deleteNotesAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete") { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

            var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
            var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

            if let tv = tableView as UITableView? {
                    context.deleteObject(self.notesList[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
                    self.notesList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                    tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
                    tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }

        return [editNotesAction, deleteNotesAction]
    }
```

Edit:
[image]

Edit2:
Just to be clear, I want the edit(programmatically added), when tapped, it will go to new note view controller.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to name it in `Storyboard Unwind Segue`.

[image]

You can find it here.

[image]

P.S: You need assign exit object like this one to create `Unwind Segue`.

[image]

Comment: where can I find this? in my tableviewcontroller or viewcnotroller

Comment: you need to fix it first before the second one.

Comment: which button or view will I assign, and why would I need an unwind segue? I am not trying to exit a segue, I am trying to connect to it.